# IBM Websphere Application Server and LTPA token generation

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-was, ltpa

I have set up the SSO between 2 WAS cells and its being verified. LDAP is being configured in both WAS cells. 
My question is how to generate the LTPA token which contains the mail or the employee id in it ? In my case the LTPA token generated contains the employee id of the user and I am expecting email id of the user in the LTPA token at receiving end. Is there any setting on WAS console which allows me to set the email id of the user in generated LTPA token ? 
I have WAS server version 8.5.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I'm sorry, I answered previously as if you were creating the LTPA token yourself.  This is what I think the issue is:

You have two cells and the two cells are using different LDAP servers.
The principal in the realm for cell1 is the employee number and the principal in cell2 is the email address.

Using LTPA for SSO assumes all cells use the same key and same registry or mirrors.  The only way that you'd be able to get this to work is to write a custom login module on the target to map the username in the token the username in the target registry.